# How to increase time to end UWSGI connection

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

Now each of my connections is closed after 60 seconds. I would like to increase this time to 300 seconds.

To do this I changed my ini file :

```
[uwsgi]
 # Django-related settings
 # the base directory (full path)
 chdir           = /home/root/djangoApp
 # Django's wsgi file
 module=djangoApp.wsgi:application

 # process-related settings
 # master
 master          = true
 # maximum number of worker processes
 processes       = 10
 # the socket (use the full path to be safe
 http          = 127.0.0.1:8000
 # ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
 chmod-socket    = 664 
 # clear environment on exit
 vacuum          = true

 protocol = uwsgi
 harakiri = 300
 http-timeout = 300
```

But it doesn't work, still the process is killed after 60 seconds.

I will be very thankful for help,

Thanks

Comment: Have you had a look at the read timeout setting? http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html#uwsgi_read_timeout

Comment: not yet ,thank you :-) could you tell me how to implement it in my ini file ?

Comment: @pritus show your nginx config please

Comment: I am not using nginx , created only uwsgi file. is nginx required ?